# How to prove two statements in propositional logic using LEAN?

Tags: theorem-proving, lean

Two proofs at the end of chapter 3 in the LEAN tutorial that I still struggle with (and hence prevent me from going further with reading the manual) are the following:

```
theorem T11 : ¬(p ↔ ¬p) := sorry
```

for which my attempt to prove the right implication stopped at this point:

```
theorem T11R : ¬(p → ¬p) := 
begin 
    assume hyp : p → ¬ p, 
    cases (em p) with hp hnp, 
    exact (hyp hp) hp, 
    exact sorry 
end
```

as obviously I don't know yet how to make use of `¬p`. Not sure how to show the left implication either. The other one is this:

```
theorem T2R : ((p ∨ q) → r) → (p → r) ∧ (q → r) := 
begin
    intros porqr, sorry
end
```

which I'm supposedly using (as the right implication) to show the following:

```
theorem T2 : ((p ∨ q) → r) ↔ (p → r) ∧ (q → r) := 
begin    
    have goR : ((p ∨ q) → r) → (p → r) ∧ (q → r), from T2R p q r,
    have goL : (p → r) ∧ (q → r) → ((p ∨ q) → r), from T2L p q r,
    exact iff.intro (goR) (goL)
end
```

Here I got the left-side going:

```
theorem T2L : (p → r) ∧ (q → r) → ((p ∨ q) → r) := 
begin
    intros prqr,
    assume porq : p ∨ q,
    exact or.elim porq prqr.left prqr.right
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theorem T11R` is not true, for example if `p` is `false` then `p → ¬ p` is true.

`¬(p ↔ ¬p)` is not equivalent to `(¬ (p → ¬ p)) ∧ ¬ (¬ p → p)`; it's equivalent to `¬ ((p → ¬ p) ∧ (¬ p → p))`, which is different.

For `theorem T2R` if you use the `split` tactic, it will give you two goals, one for each side of the `and`. You can use the `left` and `right` tactics to turn the goal `p ∨ q` into either `p` or `q`. The theorems `or.inl` and `or.inr` can be used to prove an `or` as well.

Here's a proof of `T2R`

```
theorem T2R : ((p ∨ q) → r) → (p → r) ∧ (q → r) := 
begin
    intros porqr,
    split,
    { assume hp : p,
      apply porqr,
      left,
      exact hp },
    { assume hq : q,
      apply porqr,
      right,
      exact hq },
end
```

Comment: How do you prove `T11` then? And yes, I messed up with `T2R`. The `split` tactic information is great. I suppose it comes up in a further chapter of the manual.

Comment: Hint: assume `p ↔ ¬p` and then start by trying to prove `¬p`

Comment: That's what I tried doing, but in order to do so I need to `assume hp:p` and it won't let me do so.

Comment: try `have hnp : ¬p`

Comment: I can get it to work with things like `(not_iff_self p).mp` and similar, which are not introduced until that point in the manual. But no way can I show it with the tools introduced up to the end of chapter 3. There may be a way, but I can't seem to be able to incorporate either `assume hp:p` or `have hp` or `have hnp` into my framework.

Comment: Here's a proof of `T11` ```lean theorem T11 : ¬(p ↔ ¬p) :=
begin
  assume hiff : p ↔ ¬ p,
  have hnp : ¬ p,
  { assume hp : p,
    exact hiff.mp hp hp },
  apply hnp,
  exact hiff.mpr hnp
end```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206199/discussion-between-vox-and-christopher-hughes).